# Solana contract code dependency graph

Tags: anchor

Is it possible to generate graphs from Solana/Anchor Rust code? As an example, to understand what I looking for, I will post the Solidity tool for VSC, called [Graphviz Interactive Preview](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tintinweb.graphviz-interactive-preview).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`cargo-tree`](https://crates.io/crates/cargo-tree) should give you a textual output of the dependency graph. It looks like [`cargo-graph`](https://crates.io/crates/cargo-graph) wraps it to output Graphviz DOTs (I have no experience with it though, so ymmv).